# Inner and Outer rounded border

Tags: html, css

Good day!

I am trying to make a widget, my code is as follows: http://jsfiddle.net/SeWCg/
The problem is that there is a white space between the inner and the outer rounded border.

[image: SPACE]

How can i resolve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change

```
.widget1{
    width: 218px;
    height: 210px;
    background-color: white;
}
```

to

```
.widget1{
    width: 218px;
    height: 210px;
}
```

Comment: tnx.. i overlooked the background-color: white.